# Manage enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests AFHTTPClient subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, afnetworking

I want to implement multiple Json requests from a web service with AFNetworking and this AFHTTPClient subclass to create a table View. I will create the tableView in MainViewController.

```
 #import "AFHTTPClient.h"
        @interface YlyHTTPClient : AFHTTPClient

        + ( YlyHTTPClient *)sharedHTTPClient;
        - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url;
  @end


    #import "YlyHTTPClient.h"

    static NSString * const urlString = @"http://localhost/example/";
    @implementation YplyHTTPClient

    + (YlyHTTPClient *)sharedHTTPClient {
        static YeeplyHTTPClient *_httpClient = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _httpClient = [[YlyHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            [_httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
            [_httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        });

        return _httpClient;
    }

    -(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
        self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
        if (!self) {
            return nil;
        }
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        return self;
    }
```

First I've tried to call enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequest method from the MainViewController doing this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSMutableArray *mutableRequests = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *URLString in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"users", @"projects", @"interestedUsers", nil]) {
            [mutableRequests addObject:[[YlyHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:URLString parameters:nil]];
        }

 [[YlyHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:mutableRequests progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu Completed", (unsigned long)numberOfCompletedOperations, (unsigned long)totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"Completion: %@", [operations objectAtIndex:1]); 
    }];
        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And the output that I got from the NSLog is:

```
 Completion: <AFJSONRequestOperation: 0x75dbe60, state: isFinished, cancelled: NO request: <NSMutableURLRequest http://localhost/yeeply_service/api/example/projects>, response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x72cd000>>
```

(I have three NSMutableRequest, but I only show one here).

**My first question is, How can I get data from the operations NSArray? is there no information of the JSON response in the NSArray? If there is, how can I read it as a dictionary?**

**My second question is about implement this method in my AFHTTClient subclass and call it from the ViewController using delegates, and receiving data directly in the ViewController, so that I can manage this data and set it in the tableView.**

```
-(void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:(NSArray *)urlRequests
                                      progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock 
                                    completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the question? I don't understand what you're asking here. Please, be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, actually I have two questions. First one, How can I get data from the responses that I get in the NSArray operations that I show in the NSLog at the beginning. And second, How can I manage the enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests method in the AFHTTPClient subclass and return data in a delegate to the ViewController.

Comment: Please, edit your question providing both. Try also to explain better what you would achieve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you can understand it know. I am sorry. if you can't understand I will try to do it better, but I think know it is quite better. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions in turn:

> My first question is, How can I get data from the operations NSArray?

You can get this from the `responseJSON` property of each operation in the collection:

```
for (AFJSONRequestOperation *operation in operations) {
  id JSON = operation.responseJSON;
}
```

> My second question is about implement this method in my AFHTTClient subclass and call it from the ViewController using delegates, and receiving data directly in the ViewController, so that I can manage this data and set it in the tableView.

In your subclass, create a new method with a callback block parameter with the information you need, and call that block at the end of the batch completion block.

Comment: That said, you should really follow the advice of [this answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16564035/157142). Even if this is the answer to your question, it may not be the right approach to solve your problem.